# Experiments and statistics on whether its more important to increase the efficiency of an algorithm vs. increasing CPU clock speed (processing power)

Tags: algorithm, cpu

I am currently looking into the question presented in the title. I have seen a lot of posts discussing the Big O notation, and using an example of merge sort vs bubble sort, and showing how there is a massive time difference even if the PC running the bubble sort algorithm was better. However, I was wondering if there was any experiments or statistics which have been done on such topics as I want to look into it for an essay. I have tried googling for it and using more advanced resources I have but haven't found anything.

Thank you,
Noah

Edit: Changed title to be clearer

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) applies here.  Please review the intro tour.

Comment: You might enjoy reading _Writing Efficient Programs_ by Jon Bentley - a total classic, and easy to read with easy examples (from an earlier era when many things were simpler ... yet nearly all the lessons learned then still apply).

Comment: In many cases both of the factors are quite important. We are usually not able to infinitely speed up an algorithm. Same thing with computing power, there are limits. Personally, I'd just choose some algorithms and test their times on different input: linear search vs binary search, BFS vs Dijkstra, etc. With processing it may be harder though, you may need an old PC to make some tests. Maybe you should try to find some comparisons on how many times a single operation on modern processor is faster than on older one. Usually you can say that the whole program will be also that many times faster

Comment: Yea thats essentially what I did, although I was focusing in on clock speed in comparison to making the program more efficient, so i didn't use an old PC

Comment: The link at http://hosting.astro.cornell.edu/~cordes/A6523/Bergland_Guided_Tour_FFT_1969.pdf (yes 1969) says "The Fast Fourier transform algorithm can reduce the time involved in finding a discrete Fourier transform from several minutes to less than a second, and can also lower the cost from several dollars to several cents"

Answer (score 3):

I doubt you will be able to find scientific studies on this, because it's such a well-known, easily-verifiable fact that formal research on it would be superfluous. I don't mean to imply there is anything wrong with your question, but it's a bit like looking for more advanced resources to verify that grass is green.

You should be able to find many anecdotal stories about times somebody wrote an algorithm that would have taken longer than the heat death of the universe to run, and then wrote a better algorithm that finished in two minutes. (Not all examples are this exaggerated, of course.) Those might be suitable references for your essay. But I don't think you're going to find any rigorous study systematically collecting and analysing statistics about such stories.

For one possible source of anecdotes, I recommend *The Algorithm Design Manual* (Skiena, 2008), which contains several examples such as [this one](https://www8.cs.umu.se/kurser/TDBAfl/VT06/algorithms/BOOK/BOOK/NODE38.HTM), about a supercomputer vs. a more efficient algorithm running on a regular desktop computer:

> I sped his program up by about 30,000 times. His million-dollar computer had 16 processors, each reportedly five times faster on integer computations than the $3,000 machine on my desk. That gave a maximum potential speedup of less than 100 times. Clearly, the algorithmic improvement was the big winner here, as it is certain to be in any sufficiently large computation.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I was thinking that since its such a basic idea maybe no one has done anything, but in a "previous research on topic" section I was asked to maybe insert some scientific literature on it.